# how to create a search on slider banner?

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

code:

```
<section id="featured" class="bg">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div id="main-slider" class="main-slider flexslider">
                    <ul class="slides">
                      <li>
                        <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/img/1.jpg" alt="" />
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/img/2.jpg" alt="" />
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/img/3.jpg" alt="" />
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</section>

<div class="col-lg-12">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="search file"/>
    <input type="submit" name="find" id="find" />
</div>
```

In my index page I have slider banner where three images are sliding continuously one by one. Now, I want to add search bar in the middle of slider where image can slide and search bar should be fix. How can I do this ?Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: any body can help me please

Comment: You can put your html and fix this by position absolute with banner div (relative position).

Answer (score 0):

Put the search div inside the section and make it absolute with relative to the section

```
<section id="featured" class="bg">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div id="main-slider" class="main-slider flexslider">
                <ul class="slides">
                  <li>
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/img/1.jpg" alt="" />
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/img/2.jpg" alt="" />
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/img/3.jpg" alt="" />
                  </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
<div class="col-lg-12 search_outer">
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="search file"/>
<input type="submit" name="find" id="find" />
</div>
</section>
```